# How to run a jar that uses JavaFx with the --enable-preview tag in cmd/terminal?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, javafx, jar

**Edit:** Updated my question to better reflect what my problem was. Original Question: Is there a way to prevent Jar files exported in VScode from compiling using --enable-preview?

I'm working on a java project in VScode that uses JavaFX. Whenever I export a jar of the project using the [Export Jar button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUzPz.png) and try to run the jar in cmd, I keep getting this error:

```
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class MyProgram
        java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Preview features are not enabled
        for MyProgram (class file version 61.65535). Try running with '--enable-preview'
```

Whenever I try to use the --enable-preview tag I get the following:

`Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application`

This is my JDK I use and I have JavaFX version 17.0.1.

```
openjdk version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Microsoft-28056 (build 17.0.1+12-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Microsoft-28056 (build 17.0.1+12-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Other solutions to similar problems seem to be issues with having multiple JDKs but I've only have this JDK downloaded on my device and I've only ever had this version downloaded. JavaFX is properly configured to my project and my JAVA_HOME path is to the JDK folder & Path's path is to the JDK bin.

The program runs fine when I run it in VScode, its when I export the jar and try to run it in cmd or terminal that this error pops up.

I tested it with a basic print hello world jar (not using JavaFX) and I get the same error too but no error appears when I run with the --enable-preview tag.

Comment: The "JavaFX runtime components are missing" error is not related to preview features. The error means the JavaFX classes cannot be found on the class-path/module-path at run-time. Check out [this blog](https://edencoding.com/runtime-components-error) for more information. Also, note that if you're using preview features then `--enable-preview` needs to be used at *both* compile-time and run-time.

Comment: @Slaw
If my understanding of this blog is right. I set the VM args for javafx to my project configs (`"vmArgs": "--module-path /path/to/javafx-sdk-17.0.1/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"` - I had this config set already) and I need to call those args when I try to run the jar. So would this be the proper command to input in cmd `java -jar --enable-preview MyProgram.jar --module-path /path/to/javafx-sdk-17.0.1/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`

When I run the command I still get the `JavaFX runtime components are missing`. Or did I mess up the ordering of the tags.

Comment: The `-jar <file>` should be last. Anything after is parsed as application arguments (what's passed to `main(String[])`).

Comment: This article can help you：https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/236#issuecomment-426583174

Comment: Thank you @Slaw I can run my jar without issue now. The blog was a big help.

Comment: @MingJie thank you for the link. I'll definitely look into making my project modular for a more long term fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to help in the comments & this [blog](https://edencoding.com/runtime-components-error), adding the following to your VM arguments:

`--module-path path/to/your-version-of-javafx/lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`

and running the following command in cmd/terminal

`java --enable-preview --module-path path/to/your-version-of-javafx/lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar MyProgram.jar`

Allows the jar run without errors.

The blog also has other solutions/methods to dealing with this problem as well.